# I need Help To print an Attribute belong to a WIN32_FIND_DATA struct

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to print the WIN32_FIND_DATA Attribute struct ftCreationTime, so I put %d to print it but it's giving me negative number, I tried %f and then it gave me zero, I need help please?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILETIME a ;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA x;
    HANDLE s=FindFirstFile(L"d:\\uni\\*.*",&x);
    if(s==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Search failed!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if((x.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) ==0)
        _tprintf(L"The first file name is: %s\n",x.cFileName);
    else
        _tprintf(L"The first directory name is: %s\n",x.cFileName);


    while(FindNextFile(s,&x))
    {
        if((x.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) ==0)
            _tprintf(L"The file name is: %s and the size is %d %d\n",x.cFileName,x.nFileSizeLow , x.ftCreationTime);
        else
            _tprintf(L"The directory name is: %s\n",x.cFileName );

    }
    FindClose(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`WIN32_FIND_DATA::ftCreationTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is of type [`FILETIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You need to use [`FileTimeToSystemTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert it to system time, then print it.

To print `SYSTEMTIME`, you just need to print the fields of the structure like how you print the WIN32_FIND_DATA struct.

```
SYSTEMTIME systemTime;
FileTimeToSystemTime(&x.ftCreationTime, &systemTime);
_tprintf(_T("The creation time is %02d-%02d-%d %02d:%02d:%02d\n"),
    systemTime.wMonth, systemTime.wDay, systemTime.wYear,
    systemTime.wHour, systemTime.wMinute, systemTime.wSecond);
```